# Regular expression with named subpattern doesn't see the best match

Tags: regex, pcre

When using a defined subpattern inside of reg exp, it doesn't choose the best match, but stops on the first match. Did I forget some flag?

Regular Expression: `(?<minutes>[0-9]|[1-5][0-9]):(?&minutes);`
Testing string: `47:24;`.

Expression doesn't match:

[image: pic 1 (47:24;)]

But string `47:2;` is matched correctly:

[image: pic 2 (47:2;)].

If I change 'or' condition to `[1-5][0-9]|[0-9]`, reg exp `(?<minutes>[1-5][0-9]|[0-9]):(?&minutes);` works just fine. Is there any other way to make string '47:24;' match without reversing the 'or' condition?

Comment: I see you are testing PCRE regex. I suggest using a `?` with `[1-5]`: [`(?<minutes>[1-5]?[0-9]):(?&minutes);`](https://regex101.com/r/hL6xW5/1). Or do you want to keep the alternation?

Comment: @stribizhev I would extend to `[0-5]` to allow 2 digits minutes beginning with 0

Comment: Casimir has answered this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PCRE, recursive groups are atomic (see this [article](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html)). That is why the regex engine can't backtrack in `(?&minutes)`.

In `42:24;`, the `2` of `24` is matched by the first branch `[0-9]` (since the first win), but when the pattern fails, because there's a `4` in the string and not a `;`, the regex engine can't backtrack inside the `(?&minutes)` subpattern to test the second branch `[1-5][0-9]`. *(You can take a look at the [debugger](https://regex101.com/r/sH9rD3/1))*

Solution: don't use a recursion for a so small subpattern, it's useless and make no sense (in particular if you use names for capture groups). Writing something like :

```
(?<minutes>[1-5]?[0-9]):(?<seconds>[1-5]?[0-9]);
```

or why not:

```
(?(DEFINE)(?<sex>[1-5]?[0-9]) for "sexagesimal", not for what you think)
(?<minutes>(?&sex)):(?<seconds>(?&sex));
```

seems redundant, but makes sense and is useful if you want to extract minutes and seconds (otherwise, don't use groups at all). After all, if you use named captures, your goal is not to write the shortest pattern of the world.

If you can't avoid an alternation:

- You can put the longest branch first: `[1-5][0-9]|[0-9]` as suggested by Lucas.
- you can also use mutually exclusive branches: `[1-5][0-9]?|[06-9]`, `[06-9]|[1-5][0-9]?` *(in this case the order doesn't matter)*

Note that this behaviour of recursive groups is particular to PCRE, it is different with Perl or [Ruby](http://rubular.com/r/oXj7Zsvn40).

Comment: Are you saying that to make this regular work, it is must to provide branch for the longest pattern at the first place, and so on to the smallest one?

Comment: @kos: yes, it can be understand like this (for the particular pattern).

Comment: I know that example seems useless and can be rewritten in another more convenient way, but it was a part of the one big expression using minutes, hours, day of the week and day of the month. Nevertheless thanks a lot for your detailed answer.

Comment: @kos: I was only to protect you against the madness of the *shortest pattern/funny feature/I will put it everywhere*.

Answer (score 3):

Patterns are matched left to right, and alternatives are tried left to right too. That's the way NFA regex engines work. PCRE has also has a DFA engine which will try to find the longest match, but it's not exposed to PHP.

So if you have a pattern like `a|b` and `b` is a subset of `a`, the engine will try `a` first and succeed. The `b` part will *never* be matched.

You could write `\b(?:[1-5][0-9]|[0-9])\b` but it seems redundant.

Just use `\b[1-5]?[0-9]\b` (as stribizhev suggested) to get it right all the time. `\b` is a word boundary, it'll ensure you match a whole number, and not jsut a few digits of a larger number.

Comment: @stribizhev Post your suggestion as answer... don't be shy ;)